# When powering up my raspberry i dont get a screen

Tags: display

When you plug in power cabel and hdmi with no SDcard will it promt on screen? Or do i need an OS to even get it to promt?

Just got mine and i cant get it to promt on my screen.

Comment: There will be no prompt on the screen until you put an OS to the SD card.

Answer (score 1):

The Raspberry Pi has no BIOS like a PC or laptop that you can get in for configuration without attached storage. The RasPi only has a bootloader that looks for firmware files and a kernel on a SD Card or another attached storage. If it cannot find one of them you get stuck without any prompt on a screen. For booting issues you can look at [Raspberry Pi boot modes](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/bootmodes/).

Comment: @Guest Glad to help you :-) It would be nice if you could accept the answer at the tick on the left side. This will close the question and show other users that it has a solution.